# Drupal 7 скрывает меню пользователя на странице авторизации

Tags: php, drupal

При входе на страницу авторизации, из региона, где определен блок с меню авторизации, пропадает это самое меню. Вывод `$page['usermenu']` дает пустой массив. В настройках блока список показа "Все страницы, кроме перечисленных" - пуст. Шаблон ссылок у меня прописан в `block--user--login.tpl.php`

На сколько я понял, скрытие меню спрятано где-то в недрах модуля User. Можно ли, не исправляя модуль, заставить меню отображаться всегда?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять премишины этого блока тут `admin/people/permissions`